# Linux Command to find all the client names and their mountpoints

Tags: linux, windows, client, mount-point

Is there any command so that one can get all the client names and their mount points by this single command in Linux? 
How about in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `usermount` command to list all the mount points.

But also you can give a try to check `/etc/fstab` file

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

or

```
df -k
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any command which does the same in Windows?

Comment: I will check if there is any, but can't give surety of having one.

Comment: @frhling there is one too I can find `mountvol [[drive:]path VolumeName|/l]` which can do the same in windows, by the way if it solving your problem accept the answer. Thanks